# How to pass parameter after form submit in Clickfunnel?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to track sales from different traffic sources. I have multiple sources of traffic sending clicks to my Clickfunnel landing page. I have attached utm_term parameters to the links from different traffic sources.

So the utm_term parameter is now on the landing page (1st page of my funnel), but after I optin and submit form to move to the second page, the parameter is gone.

How can I store the parameter somewhere and pass it along down the funnel (2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th page)?

Ultimately, I need to pass that parameter into a button href on the 2nd page.

--

Edit: I'm using this script from [DevQuickie](https://devquickie.com/2018/03/20/add-utm-tags-to-all-page-links-and-buttons-in-clickfunnels/) to insert the utm_term into buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/devQuickie/queryparams-to-a/f702ad7c/script.js"></script>
```

But I need to find out how to capture the parameter and pass it after submitting a form.

Alternatively, I think the [concept of this](https://whiskeyneat.com/how-to-forward-url-parameters-in-clickfunnels-pages) works but it doesn't seem to work with "button actions" in Clickfunnel:

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var newParam = getParameterByName('parameter')
var nextURL3 = ('https://www.yourdomain.com/pagepath\?parameter\=' + newParam);
</script>
```

Button code:

```
<div class="de elBTN elAlign_center elMargin0 ui-droppable de-editable" id="tmp_button-86409" data-de-type="button" data-de-editing="false" data-title="button" data-ce="false" data-trigger="none" data-animate="fade" data-delay="500" style="margin-top: 30px; outline: none; cursor: pointer; display: block;" aria-disabled="false" data-elbuttontype="1">
<a onclick="location.href=nextURL3;" class="elButton elButtonSize1 elButtonColor1 elButtonRounded elButtonPadding2 elBtnVP_10 elButtonCorner3 elBtnHP_25 elBTN_b_1 elButtonShadowN1 elButtonTxtColor1 elButtonFull" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 600; background-color: rgb(1, 116, 199); font-size: 26px;">
<span class="elButtonMain"><i class="fa_prepended fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Button Text Goes Here<i class="fa_appended fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>
<span class="elButtonSub"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Code, or it never happened.

Comment: @Dementic edited and added more codes and descriptions. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Please check clickfunnel document I think they have mentioned that. As I was using funnelflux and Voluum they have clearly mentioned that. @Jeff

Comment: I can't seem to find anything in its documentations..

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. It's better if you can add the parameters on the server when rendering the page, but if all you have is JavaScript, here is one way to solve the problem.

1. Give the button an ID: `<a id="trackme" href="https://...">`
2. Set the `href` using JavaScript.

   ```
   // parse the current page search params
   const pageSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
   // find the button on the page
   const button = document.querySelector('#trackme')
   // parse the url from the button
   const href = new URL(button.href)
   // parse the search params from the url
   const buttonSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(href.search)
   // set the search param you want from the page
   buttonSearchParams.set("utm_term", pageSearchParams.get("utm_term"))
   // update the search for the url
   href.search = buttonSearchParams.toString()
   // update the button url
   button.href = href.toString()
   ```

[Window Location docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

[URLSearchParams docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Can you briefly explain what this piece of code does? With Clickfunnel, when submitting email optin forms, the button action is set to "submit form", but I can grab the button #ID and sub it into the javascript. (Refer to: https://www.screencast.com/t/jfkSSqTz)