# Can I pass contact form parameters in URL in ClickFunnel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I designed a contact form on ClickFunnel. I just wanted to know If it's really possible to pass form field parameters in URL on submit the form in ClickFunnel?.

After Google, I found silimar answer but that's not working in my case.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152702/how-to-pass-parameter-after-form-submit-in-clickfunnel
```

The answer is not very clear, still I tried to write a complete script with hope that it would work but I' m getting **null** value in URL.

How can I do that with button id and onclick function?
Any suggestion

Script

```
<script>

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var newParam = getParameterByName('CompanyName')
    var nextURL3 = ('https://caterlyapp.azurewebsites.net/Signup1Step.aspx\?CompanyName\=' + newParam);
    </script>
```

Button:

```
<a onclick="location.href=nextURL3;>Hook Me Up!<a>"
```

Output:

```
https://mydomain/SignupStep.aspx/?CompanyName=NULL
```

Form Sample

[image]

Comment: what would be your expected out - Not sure how and where you want to pass something to where ? How does your URL looks like ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Thanks for your time. 
I' m designing a form on Clickfunnel and they guys only allow you to write custom css and js if you want customizations. By default, after submit it redirects to /Signup page. 
I want to show the parameters in URL like name, phone, email etc.

Comment: Where do these names, email etc comes form ? Can you add a minimal working example of this form ? you can append some parameters to this redirect URL - Correct ? and these values comes from the form

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
It's just a page builder that let you allow to design a from and set an action like where you want it to redirect.  For your help, let me share one screenshot here

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
I just updated my question with screenshot of how I designed a form.Please check

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
For your convenience, this is the URL

https://go.caterly.app/free-demo-and-60-day-trial36970787

Please visit the link and click on button 14 days Trial and submit the form to see how the URL works.

Comment: The problem how can you fetch those values from the form when clicking on Hook Me up ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
As they guys can't give you access over php code so I tried to do it by writing script and calling a script on button click. Did you read my question properly, I tried to explain how I' m doing that

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Just to mention, the button I shared above in my code is the same button "Hook me Up". I just updated the name.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Any luck :(